# Media Queries -- Screen, Print, Speech in Responsive Design

Tags: css, media-queries

I (like the rest of the world) use media queries to help with responsive design.  As such, I am usually focused on writing a `@media screen` query.

But I am wondering - do I need to take screen readers (or even printers?) into consideration when using media queries for responsive design?  I.e., are there situations where I would need to use `@media speech` in responsive design? If so, how.

And responsive design is irrelevant to speech readers, then when would I need to use a media query for a speech reader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments in the issue [[mediaqueries-4 ] Deprecate 'speech' media type as well?](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1751) there is currently neither a clear use-case nor any notable support for `speech`.

So based on that you currently don’t need to care about the `speech` media type.

The `print` media query on the other can be useful depending on what information your site provides, and if you want to hide e.g. the navigation of the website and include some contact information on the bottom of the site. Or change the font-family to a serife one that is easier to read when printed.

Comment: Thanks -- much appreciated.